# Skipping loop optimisation error in tensorflow_serving

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-serving

I am getting the following message when testing a model with tensorflow_serving,
can u please help me debug and understand what it means

```
2022-02-13 23:20:52.460513: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:486] Finished adding/updating models
2022-02-13 23:20:52.460589: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:367] Profiler service is enabled
2022-02-13 23:20:52.461847: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:393] Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:8500 ...
[warn] getaddrinfo: address family for nodename not supported
[evhttp_server.cc : 245] NET_LOG: Entering the event loop ...
2022-02-13 23:20:52.463794: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:414] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:8501 ...
2022-02-13 23:21:14.903736: W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/loop_optimizer.cc:906] Skipping loop optimization for Merge node with control input: StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/Incompatible_Data_Type_6/AssertGuard/branch_executed/_539
```

thanks